# Non iterative equivalent for reversing a linked list

Tags: c++

I am reading about list traversals in Algorithms book by RobertSedwick. Function definitions are shown below. It is mentioned that it is possible to have traverse and remove functions can have iterative counter parts, but traverseR cannot have. My question why traverseR cannot have iterative counter part? Is it that if recursive call is not end of function i.e., like in traverse  then we cannot have iterative, Is my understanding right?

Thanks for your time and help.

```
void traverse(link h, void visit(link))
  { 
    if (h == 0) return;
    visit(h); 
    traverse(h->next, visit);
  }
void traverseR(link h, void visit(link))
  { 
    if (h == 0) return;
    traverseR(h->next, visit);
    visit(h); 
  }
void remove(link& x, Item v)
  { 
    while (x != 0 && x->item == v) 
      { link t = x; x = x->next; delete t; }
    if (x != 0) remove(x->next, v); 
  }
```

Comment: Not sure I 100% understand the question, but: You can only move forwards through a linked list (each item contains a link to the next one, but not the previous). By going recursively through, you can visit each item before *or* after you move on, hence making it look like you can go backwards. I.e. you can cheat and use the function stack to remember where you've already been.

Comment: Basically your understanding is correct. You can look for [tail recursion](http://www.google.de/search?q=tail+recursion) and related topics like tail call elimination for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`traverseR` uses the call stack to store pointers to all the nodes of the list, so that they can be accessed in reverse order as the call stack unwinds.

In order to do this without a call stack (i.e. non-recursively), you'll need some other stack-like data structure to store these pointers in.

The other functions simply work on the current node and move on, with no need to store anything for use after the recursive function call returns. This means that the *tail recursion* can be replaced with a loop (either by modifying the code or, depending on the compiler, letting it determine that that's possible and make the transformation itself).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the list is single-linked, it is not possible to visit it iteratively in the backward order because there's no pointer from a node to a previous node.

What the recursive implementation of `traverseR` essentially does is that it implicitly reverses the list and visits it in the forward order.

Comment: I see nothing that could reasonably be called implicitly reversing the list in `traverseR`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: it creates a copy of every node in the reverse order on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You could write and iterative version of `traverseR` using a stack: in a loop iterate from one node to another, pushing the nodes on the stack. When you get to the end of the list then, in another loop, pop and visit the nodes you visited.

But his is basically what the recursive version does.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to traverse a singly linked list in reverse order with only O(1) extra space -- i.e., without a stack of previously visited nodes. It is, however, a little tricky, and not at all thread safe.

The trick to this is to traverse the list from beginning to end, reversing it in place as you do so, then traverse it back to the beginning, reversing it again on the way back through.

Since it is a linked list, reversing it in place is fairly straightforward: as you get to a node, save the current value of its `next` pointer, and overwrite that with the address of the previous node in the list (see the code for more detail):

```
void traverseR(node *list, void (*visit)(node *)) { 
    node *prev = nullptr;
    node *curr = list;
    node *next;

    if (!curr)
        return;

    // Traverse forwards, reversing list in-place as we go.
    do {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    } while (curr->next);

    // fix up so we have a fully reversed list
    curr->next = prev;
    prev = nullptr;

    // Traverse the reversed list, visiting each node and reversing again
    do { 
        visit(curr);
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    } while (curr->next);
}
```

Like almost anything dealing with linked lists, I feel obliged to add that (at least IMO) they should almost always be treated as a purely intellectual exercise. Using them in real code is *usually* a net loss. You typically end up with code that's slow, fragile, and hard to understand, as well as typically wasting quite a bit of memory (unless the data you store in each node is pretty big, the pointer can often use as much space as the data itself).

Answer (score 0):

> My question why traverseR cannot have iterative counter part? Is it that if recursive call is not end of function i.e., like in traverse then we cannot have iterative, Is my understanding right?

Correct. The functions `traverse` and `remove` end with a call to themselves. They are tail recursive functions. The call in `traverseR` to itself is not at the end of the function; `traverseR` is not tail recursive.

Recursion in general has an expense of creating and later destroying stack frames. This expense can be completely avoided with tail recursive functions by changing the recursion into iteration. Most compilers recognize tail recursive functions and convert the recursion to iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write an iterative version of `traverseR` depending on what you mean by iterative.  If you are limited so a single traversal through the list, it is not possible.  But if you can sacrifice a lot processing time it can be done.  It does use less memory in the classic speed vs. memory trade-off.

```
void traverseRI(link h, void visit(link))
{
    if (h == 0) return;

    link last = 0;

    while (last != h)
    {
        link test = h;
        while (test->next != last)
        {
            test = test->next;
        }

        visit(test);
        last = test;
    }
}
```