# what's wrong with my reverse singly linked list function code?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a linked list and finding problem with running it.
the code just produces error that upon displaying it. it enters to an infinite loop when displaying. Do I have the right step?

```
void Header::reverse()
{
    Node* nodePtr = head;
    Node* first = head;
    Node* temp = NULL;
    while(nodePtr)
    {
        temp = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        temp->next = first;
        first = temp;
    }
    head = first;
}
```

and here's part of my class code
....

```
enter code here
class Header
{
 private:
  struct Node
   {
 Node* next;
 int value;
   };
 Node* head;
```

.....

can anyone tell my what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Any problem in particular?

Comment: Maybe we can if you tell what is the *exact* error you are having

Comment: the code just produces error that upon displaying it. it enters to an infinite loop when displaying.

Comment: @LeonardLie: what exactly do you mean by "displaying"?

Comment: after appending 5 numbers to the list, it correctly displays (e.x. 5 4 3 2 1 from head to tail) but after reversing it, upon displaying it shows infinite loop of (5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12266239/179910).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first must be NULL on start, otherwise in the first iteration you are essentially doing

```
head->next = head;
```

Comment: bravo thanks a bunch. that did it. that was fast. i appreciate your help sir loghorn!